# Get time from date and databse then compare these time in java

Tags: java, database, date, time, compare

I have a date: *actDate*, and its time was extracted as string *timeFromAct*

Then I have a reference time from database: *timeValue*, this was converted to string as *timeFromDB*

```
DateFormat formatTime;
formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
Date actDate = actinfo.getActDate();
String timeFromAct = formatDay.format(actDate);

String date= ListOfConstants.SOME_DATE_REF;
ResultTable[] timeValue = RTManager.getSomethingDecodeList(date);
String timeFromDB = Arrays.toString(timeValue);
```

I know converting the two as Strings won't let me compare the 2 times but

I would like to know how do I compare these time values in an if statement (similar to below comparison)?

```
if (timeFromAct is greater than or equal to timeFromDB){
*some codes*
}
```

Comment: `actDate.before(timeFromDB)`  or  `actDate.compareTo(timeFromDB)`

Comment: if both strings are in the `HH:mm:ss` format they can be compared by the  `compareTo` method of `String` (if you really need to compare as text). I would prefer to transform that strings to `LocalTime` (or so) and then compare using theirs `compareTo`

Comment: @weaver I do not believe that `Date` has a `compareTo(String)` method

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger see this. Date has compareTo function [Date javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat` classes. They are not only long outdated along with `Date`, they are also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Using `LocalTime` from java.time is a good idea, @CarlosHeuberger. Simpler and clearer than `compareTo`, use its `isBefore` method. Use “not before” to mean “same time or after”.

Comment: What are the capabilities of your `ResultTable` class? What does `timeFromDB` look like exactly? Asking because I suspect that there’s an easier way than converting to string and back.

Comment: hi @OleV.V., unfortunately i cannot import java.time from where i'm doing the codes. ResultTable gets the value of time (HH:mm:ss) from database.

Comment: So `Arrays.toString(timeValue)` might give you `[]` or `[23:32:45]` or `[09:36:29, 11:12:12]` depending on the length of the array? What would be the desired result in each case?

Comment: What’s your Java version? java.time is built in from Java 8 and on. To use it with Java 6 or 7 you will need [the ThreeTen Backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and import `org.threeten.bp.LocalTime` and froends.

Comment: it will surely return only 1 value like this: [23:32:45]. @OleV.V.

Comment: @drowny and by that documentation (and also by the Java 10 version of it) its argument is **not** a `String` ,is it? I definitively put that in my comment and `timeFromDB`, as suggested by @weaver, happens to be a  `String` (part of the question)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger In Date library compareTo gives date to compare.In question both dates are String and same format like HH:mm:ss , questioner said.

Comment: @drowny OK, but `actDate` as used by @weaver is a `Date`, not a `String`. And **you** posted the link to the method of the `Date` class...

Comment: yes @weaver used as Date. But in question both are String , so i provided to compare these string with compareTo which is using in String library. I posted 2 solution, one of them is with Date comparasion and other one related as String comparasion usage.

Comment: @drowny I was meaning your reply: "@CarlosHeuberger see this. Date has compareTo function Date javadoc", to my comment: "@weaver I do not believe that Date has a compareTo(String) method" (I am **not** commenting your answer, this is the questions section)

Answer (score 1):

Write like this ;

```
if (actDate.after(timeFromDb) || actDate.compareTo(timeFromDB)==0 ){
*some codes*
}
```

In detail

- `actDate.after(timeFromDb)` provides greater than case.
- `actDate.compareTo(timeFromDB)==0` provides equality of `actDate` and
  `timeFormDb`.

Or in String comparasion if both are same format ;

```
if(timeFromAct.compareTo(timeFromDB) > 0 || timeFromAct .equals(timeFromDB)){..}
```

or more simple

```
if(!(timeFromAct.compareTo(timeFromDB) < 0)){..}
```

String.compareTo works as

```
"a".compareTo("b"); // returns a negative number, here -1
"a".compareTo("a"); // returns  0
"b".compareTo("a"); // returns a positive number, here 1
```

Comment: hi @drowny, i have 2 time with same format but in string.
`String timeFromAct = formatDay.format(actDate);`
`String timeFromDB = Arrays.toString(timeValue);`
Will this work if both time are in string?
`if (timeFromAct.after(timeFromDb) || actDate.compareTo(timeFromDB)==0 )`

Comment: If both are in string, Do it directly like `if(timeFromAct > timeFromDB || timeFromAct .equals(timeFromDB)){..}`

Comment: i just tried but error occurred: `operator > cannot be applied to java.lang.String,java.lang.String`

Comment: Sory change with this `if(timeFromAct.compareTo(timeFromDB) > 0 || timeFromAct .equals(timeFromDB)){..}` . I updated the post

Comment: can you please explain the compareTo part? does it mean if i want `timeFromAct` < `timeFromDB`, i can simply write `(timeFromAct.compareTo(timeFromDB) < 0` ?

Comment: Yes i explained in my post. you can check. CompareTo makes a string comparasion. If  timeFromAct smaller than timeFromDb , it returns negative number. If not returns positive number. if equal returns zero. and you can compare with it

Comment: thank you, @drowny. are the following correct? 
`21:59:59.compareTo(22:00:00) -> returns -1`
`22:00:01.compareTo(22:00:00) -> returns 1`

Comment: of course true like your said. Your comparable statement should be zero. If return smaller than zero --> this is smaller. If return greater than zero --> this is greater. If returns zero. they are equal.

Comment: @dcdum2018 why do you not just test it? Java 10 has the very helpful command `jshell` - so you don't need to write a whole program to test just that commands You should write `"21:59:59".compareTo("22:00:00")`, that is, using quotes

Comment: dit it worked correctly? i will try with java 10 thx @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: @drowny that comment was meant to "dcdum2018" - that's why I wrote `@dcdum2018` at the beginning - he should test it

Answer (score 1):

### LocalTime from java.time

```
    Date actDate = actinfo.getActDate();
    ResultTable[] timeValue = RTManager.getSomethingDecodeList(date);

    LocalTime actualTime = actDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalTime();
    if (timeValue.length == 1) {
        LocalTime timeFromDB = LocalTime.parse(timeValue[0].toString());
        if (! actualTime.isBefore(timeFromDB)) {
            System.out.println("timeFromAct is greater than or equal to timeFromDB");
        } else {
            System.out.println("timeFromAct is less than timeFromDB");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unexpected number of ResultTable entries: " + timeValue.length);
    }
```

A `LocalTime` is a time of day without date and without time zone. I believe that this is exactly what you need.

I have assumed that `getActDate` invariably returns an old-fashoined `Date` object. It would be better if you can modify it to return an appropriate type from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

In the conversion from `Date` to `LocalTime` in the above code you will need to get your time zone right, or you will get incorrect results. I have tentatively assumed the JVM time zone setting, notated as `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, since the `SimpleDateFormat` in your question used this; but this is fragile since the setting can be changed from another part of your program or another program running in the same JVM. Better if you can specify the correct time zone like for example `ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila")`.

Do check your assumptions. `RTManager.getSomethingDecodeList` will surely return only 1 value like this: [23:32:45]. The check costs so little, and it will be expensive to track down the bug if some day a new programmer on your project modifies it to return an array of a different length. Do help by issuing a helpful error message in this case.

The date-time classes that you used — `DateFormat`,  `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` — are long outdated and poorly designed. The first two in particular are renowned for being troublesome. I see no reason why you should want to use any of those if you can avoid it.

> unfortunately i cannot import java.time from where i'm doing the codes.

If you are using at least Java 6, you can use java.time.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.